# Image transform on view

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm curious about an image effect on [this website](http://thewhitwell.com/). Specifically, how the images "unravel" from the left to the right on view as you scroll past them.

I've saved the website to my desktop and cut away all of the unnecessary CSS/Javascript/HTML. I come up with this:

```js
$.fn.is_on_screen = function(e) {
    // e.prevenDefault();
    var win = $(window);
    //Object to Check
    obj = $(this);
    // return false;
    //the top Scroll Position in the page
    var scrollPosition = win.scrollTop();
    //the end of the visible area in the page, starting from the scroll position
    var visibleArea = parseInt(win.scrollTop() + win.height());

    var vercible_height = win.height() / 2;
    //the end of the object to check
    var objEndPos = parseInt(obj.offset().top + obj.outerHeight());
    if (visibleArea >= objEndPos) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('clicked')) {
            if (!(obj.hasClass('inner-box'))) {
                obj.addClass('inner-box');
                obj.width('100%');
            }
        }
    }
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.inner-box').length > 0) {
        $('.inner-box').removeClass('inner-box');
    }
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    left_nav_click();
    find_active_contnt();
    onScroll();
});
$(window).on('load', function() {
    manage_height();
});


$(document).on("scroll", function() {
    onScroll();
    find_on_scroll()
});

function left_nav_click() {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // $(document).off("scroll");
        $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 2
        }, 600, 'swing', function() {
            // window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            find_active_contnt();
        });
    });
}

function onScroll(event) {
    var counter = 0;
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    /* if (counter <= 10) {
         manage_height();
     }
     counter += 1;*/
    $('#menu a').each(function() {
        var currLink = $(this);

        //if(currLink.attr("href") != '#home'){

        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));

        if (refElement.length > 0) {
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                if (currLink.attr("href") == '#home') {
                    $('#fd').hide();
                } else {
                    $('#fd').show();
                }
                $('#menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
                //var new_text = currLink.text();
                var new_text = currLink.data('text');
                $('#fd').find('.text-change').children('span').text(new_text);
            } else {
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        }

    });
}

function manage_height() {
    if ($('.inner-img').length > 0) {
        $('.inner-img').map(function() {
            $(this).height($(this).children('img').height());
            $(this).width('80%');
        });
    }
    if ($('.buttons').length > 0) {
        $('.buttons').map(function() {
            $(this).width('80%');
        });
    }
}

function find_on_scroll() {
    if ($('.inner-img').length > 0) {
        $('.inner-img').map(function() {
            $(this).is_on_screen();
        });
    }
    if ($('.buttons').length > 0) {
        $('.buttons').map(function() {
            $(this).is_on_screen();
        });
    }
}

function find_active_contnt() {
    var new_text = '';
    $('#menu a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            new_text = $(this).data('text');
        }
    });
    $('#fd').find('.text-change').children('span').text(new_text);
}


(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        var headerHeight = $('.nav-scroll .mob-head').outerHeight(true);
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (scrolled > scroll) {
                $('#sth').removeClass('time');
                $('.nav-scroll').removeClass('fixed');
            } else {
                $('#sth').addClass('time');
                $('.nav-scroll').addClass('fixed');
            }
            scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.image-sec ul li .inner{float:left;width:100%;transition:width 2s ease;-ms-transition:width 2s ease;-moz-transition:width 2s ease;-webkit-transition:width 2s ease;-o-transition:width 2s ease;background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-ms-background-size:cover;}
.image-sec ul li .inner.inner-box{width:100%;}
.inner-img{background-position:50% 50%;background-size:cover;-webkit-background-size:cover;-moz-background-size:cover;-o-background-size:cover;-ms-background-size:cover;width:100%;transition:all 2s ease;-ms-transition:all 2s ease;-moz-transition:all 2s ease;-webkit-transition:all 2s ease;-o-transition:all 2s ease;}
img.hidden-img{max-width:none;opacity:0;visibility:hidden;width:100%;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0023)http://thewhitwell.com/ -->
<html class="js csstransitions"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>The Whitwell</title>
    <link href="css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scroll-menu.js"></script>


</style></head>
    


                                <div class="mar wide mar-bottom">
                                    <div class="inner-img inner-box" style="height: 800px; width: 100%; background-image: url(&quot;http://thewhitwell.com/images/uploads/ww-lobby.jpg&quot;);">
                                        <img src="ww-lobby.jpg" class="hidden-img">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>



</body></html>
► Run code snippetCopy snippet to answer
```

Comment: You should be more clear in your question.

Comment: I don't understand your statement. I thought I was very clear. I want to replicate the image "unravel" effect on the example website. But I cannot do so with the code I provided. How can I be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't imported jquery lib.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Add this to your website head and it'll works

Live codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqgWpo